# pig does not load map data USING PigStorage

Tags: apache-pig

I tried to load data from this file named `data`

```
(1,[open#apache])
(2,[apache#hadoop])
```

with this pig script

```
A = LOAD 'data' USING PigStorage(' ') as (col1:int, M:map []);
```

but i got

```
(,)
(,)
```

please help me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can fix your code like this :

```
A = LOAD 'data' USING PigStorage(' ') as (a:tuple(col1:int, M:map []));
DUMP A;
```

would give you

```
((1,[open#apache]))
((2,[apache#hadoop]))
```